# Machine learning course by andrew exercise can run locally but fail to submit?

Tags: machine-learning, octave

I am learning machine learning course in coursera and doing the exercise of neural networks. My code can run locally and return the right answer, but it shows wrong when I submit it in octave.
[image]

the picture showed that the cost values are right. but when I submit it, the answer is like this:

[image]

this means `y` is out of bound, and in my script `y` is the label of 5000 samples, it should have 5000 rows, and what happened to `y`, and why do not occurred while running locally.

files are here:
[ex4](https://github.com/BangShen/machine-learning-coursera-course-problems-solving/blob/master/machine-learning-ex4/ex4/ex4.m),[nncostfunction](https://github.com/BangShen/machine-learning-coursera-course-problems-solving/blob/master/machine-learning-ex4/ex4/nnCostFunction.m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the exercise itself assumes 5000 observations, a much smaller number of observations is used to evaluate your code for submission.

You hardcoded the number 5000 in your code, rather than using a variable which captures the number of observations (presumably `m` in the code). Therefore in your for loop, once you've gone past 16, which presumably is the number of observations used in the submission context, octave complains that you're trying to access an index that is undefined for that particular array.

Long story short you should have used `for i = 1:m` rather than `for i = 1:5000`, to make your code generalise to sample sizes different to 5000.

Comment: Thanks, Tasos, your answer does really solve my issues, I eliminate this problem immediately.